# Open script in Windows Terminal PowerShell instead of normal PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-terminal

I want to open a PowerShell script in the Windows Terminal instead of the normal PowerShell terminal.

The command I use to open this script is

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\username\Documents\A1111 Web UI Autoinstaller\Launcher\LauncherUI.ps1" skip no-autolaunch`

However, this opens the script in a normal PowerShell window:

[image]

I would like to open it in my Windows Terminal PowerShell window:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You could basically run the program from the which console host you want to use.

```
# Use conhost
conhost.exe powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "script.ps1"

# Use wt
wt.exe powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "script.ps1"
```

---

Or, you can set Windows Terminal as default console host.

On **Windows Terminal**, go to **Settings** > **Startup** > **Default Terminal Application** > **Windows Terminal**

[image: windows terminal]

On **Conhost**, right click the title bar > **Defaults** > **Terminal** **Default Terminal Application** > **Windows Terminal**

[image: console host]

Comment: Point of note: These settings are version specific. So, for those not on the version you are demo'ing on, then those settings are moot.